# Verify connection pool size assigned in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, connection-pooling

We use for configuring org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource datasource. Going through the forums I saw that the property 'maxActive' defines max number of concurrent connections. How do we verify/make sure that it sets correctly. Below are my configuration file in Spring and we use Hibernate4 as ORM

`<bean id="AAADataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"></property>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1"></property>
        <property name="maxActive" value="300"></property>
        <property name="initialSize" value="50"></property>
    </bean>`

Answer (score 0):

set small value and test with load test(jmeter,jperf...)  and using monitor tool to check. You can use jvisualvm that ship with JDK to monitor.

Comment: My understanding is that jvisualvm is for monitoring JVM(CPU,Threads,GC and PermGen). How do we check connections count ?

Comment: It allow you attach to JMX and see clearly info about connection pool. I'm used that to monitor c3p0 pool before

Comment: Easy way is you using jconsole and attach to java local process

Comment: If you still feel hard. Please check my guide [using jconsole to profile](http://devjav.com/profile-java-web-application-run-tomcat-using-jconsole/)

Answer (score 0):

Various properties can be made readable during runtime via JMX using [commons-dbcp-jmx](http://nicoulaj.github.io/commons-dbcp-jmx/), including the [maxActive](http://nicoulaj.github.io/commons-dbcp-jmx/commons-dbcp-jmx-jdbc4/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/ManagedBasicDataSource.html#getMaxActive%28%29) property. The JDK includes JConsole and JVisualVM which can show MBeans properties retrieved via JMX. The JConsole can connect to any local running Java process and shows the MBean-properties on the "MBeans" tab.